# What is that selector next to class?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a piece of code and found out that there is something called "data-flow-localize" in the span tag.

I googled it, but couldn't find anything about it.

Do you know what is that selector (sorry if that's not the right name) doing?

Does someone know what "data-flow-localize" is calling?

Thanks.

```
   <span class="price after_special " data-flow-localize="item-price"> $0.00 - $250.00 </span>
```

My end goal is to modify price section so it reads "Starting at " +[minimun_price].

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: It's called an `attribute`. It's not calling anything, it's just markup so it can be used by something - perhaps JS or even CSS.

Comment: CSS has selectors. That's an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> My end goal is to modify price section so it reads "Starting at "
>   +[minimun_price].

To do that you can use the `::before` pseudo-element:

```css
span.price.after_special::before {
  content: 'Starting at: ';
}
```

```html
<span class="price after_special " data-flow-localize="item-price"> $0.00 - $250.00 </span>
```